# preseed ubuntu 14.04 vim-nox package not available

Tags: system-installation, preseed

I am remastering Ubuntu 14.04.4 ISO and preseeding.
When installing some additional packages like so:

```
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server ntp curl vim-nox
```

vim-nox is not available, but the rest are. I have universe and other repos enabled in the preseed file like so:

```
d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true
d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true
d-i apt-setup/backports boolean true
d-i apt-setup/multiverse boolean true
```

Is there some refresh not happening or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this was my mistake. I am configuring for a specific subnet that is not available in my testing environment. Clearly any packages not on the installation media would be unavailable. I won't be able to confirm this with testing until next week, but it seems pretty clear this is the cause.